# Error while deploying the balance-transfer sample app hyperledger fabric-samples

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

Can someone help me in fixing the below timeout issue while instantiating the chaincode operation of the balance-transfer app which is a part of fabric-samples?

```
recoveryParam: 0 }
error: [Peer.js]: sendProposal - timed out after:60000
error: [Peer.js]: sendProposal - timed out after:60000
error: [client-utils.js]: sendPeersProposal - Promise is rejected: Error: REQUEST_TIMEOUT
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/home/ubuntu/fabric-samples/balance-transfer/node_modules/fabric-client/lib/Peer.js:124:19)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:498:11)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:323:5)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:290:5)
error: [client-utils.js]: sendPeersProposal - Promise is rejected: Error: REQUEST_TIMEOUT
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/home/ubuntu/fabric-samples/balance-transfer/node_modules/fabric-client/lib/Peer.js:124:19)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:498:11)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:323:5)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:290:5)
[2018-10-11 13:25:07.151] [ERROR] instantiate-chaincode - instantiate proposal was bad
[2018-10-11 13:25:22.593] [ERROR] instantiate-chaincode - instantiate proposal was bad
[2018-10-11 13:25:34.602] [DEBUG] instantiate-chaincode - Failed to send Proposal and receive all good ProposalResponse
[2018-10-11 13:25:45.807] [ERROR] instantiate-chaincode - Failed to instantiate. cause:Failed to send Proposal and receive all good ProposalResponse
(node:3678) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Failed to instantiate. cause:Failed to send Proposal and receive all good ProposalResponse
    at Object.instantiateChaincode (/home/ubuntu/fabric-samples/balance-transfer/app/instantiate-chaincode.js:190:9)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:189:7)
(node:3678) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:3678) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
^C
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a problem in the documentation.

The JSON payload for the instantiate command is missing the 'peers' definition. It should be:

```
curl -s -X POST \
  http://localhost:4000/channels/mychannel/chaincodes \
  -H "authorization: Bearer <put JSON Web Token here>" \
  -H "content-type: application/json" \
  -d '{
    "peers": ["peer0.org1.example.com","peer1.org1.example.com"],
    "chaincodeName":"mycc",
    "chaincodeVersion":"v0",
    "chaincodeType": "golang",
    "args":["a","100","b","200"]
}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have `hyperledger/fabric-ccenv:<version>` image. It is required to form the chaincode container during instantiation of chaincode.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, Instantiation will take more time for execution, you can increase the timeout for instantiation in the code, [In this line](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/94c21eb9bd6f6ac808e189259bc1abec756694e6/balance-transfer/app/instantiate-chaincode.js#L68)

```
let results = await channel.sendInstantiateProposal(request, 120000);
```

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue, got it fixed following the below steps

1. Firstly delete all the docker container and images.
2. Restart the docker
3. Download all the images again and increase the timeout time in the app folder

   let results = await channel.sendInstantiateProposal(request, 120000);
4. If error still coming, try to run the ./runApp.sh and ./testAPI.sh using sudo.